# Trimming the end of string contains (#) - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I'm having trouble trimming off some characters at the end of a string. The string usually looks like: (the number in the () is changing), I want to remove the () including the value inside, i added the Trim() and the end to remove spaces

```
$string = CollectorDCFService (1)
$string = LogicalShadowDatabase (3)
```

I tried to replace it with ""

```
$string.Replace("([0-9])"," ").Trim()
$string.Replace("(\*)"," ").Trim()
```

Its nor working...

Comment: I think `.Trim()` does not work as you may think it does. ;-)  Try `$string -replace '\(|\)'`

Comment: Doesn't work Replace("\(|\)","")

Comment: Yes I did .....

Comment: As I wrote above. its not working. you can try it and see

Comment: Please try it the way I posted it ... do not use the dot net method ... use the `-replace` operator!!!  `$string -replace '\(|\)'`

Comment: I tried!!! from ProbeService (5) --> ProbeService 5

Comment: If its not working for me its defiantly doesn't work for you. did you tried it?????

Comment: Maybe this? $string -replace '[\(\d+)]',''

Comment: Would `$string.Substring(0, $string.indexof("(")  ).trim()` do what you want?

Comment: @Olaf, the confusion was over the desired outcome, which was to remove the entire `<space>(<digits>)` suffix. The problem wasn't with the `.Trim()` but with the attempt to first replace the `(<digits>)` suffix with a space using `.Replace()`; if the latter had worked, the `.Trim()` would have worked too (but a regex can be formulated in a way that doesn't require a separate `.Trim()` call).

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for hte clarification. I understood he wanted to remove only the parenthesis. He just could have said he wanted to remove the parenthasis INCLUDING the numbers inside the parenthesis. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Why not just do this:    ```'CollectorDCFService (1)' -replace '\(|\)'```?    ***The results are***   ```CollectorDCFService 1```. Increasing the digit count; ```'CollectorDCFService (100)' -replace '\(|\)'```, and we get ```CollectorDCFService 100```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The [`String.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) .NET *method* only supports *literal* (verbatim) string replacements, so you cannot use [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) constructs such as `[0-9]` with it.
- Use the regex-based [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) *operator* instead:
- Formulate the regex in a way that makes a separate `.Trim()` call (to remove the spaces preceding `(…)`) unnecessary:

```bash
$strings = 'CollectorDCFService (1)', 'LogicalShadowDatabase (3)'

# -> 'CollectorDCFService', 'LogicalShadowDatabase'
$strings -replace '\s+\([0-9]+\)$'
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/N9ZC1d/1).

Comment: Thank you @mklement0 I guess its working to more than one digit right? do I need to add the trim() at the end in order to remove spaces?

Comment: @Bandit, yes, it works for multiple digits too, and as long as all space occur _before_ the `(...)`, no `.Trim()` is necessary - please see the update with the [regex101.com link](https://regex101.com/r/N9ZC1d/1).